# Sequelize "Instagram like follower" model?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Sorry about the title; I didn't know how to word it any better. But what I'm trying to achieve is as simple as `User A` can follow `User B`. The problem I'm having is that `User A` can follow `User B` multiple times. I'm unsure how to prevent this using `Sequelize`?

Follower Model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var followers = sequelize.define('followers', {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      referenceces: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'userId'
      }
    }, 
    followerId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      referenceces: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'userId'
      }
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      // associate: function(models) {
      //   followers.belongsTo(models.user, {
      //     onDelete: "CASCADE",
      //     foreignKey: {
      //       allowNull: false
      //     }
      //   });
      // },
    },
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
  });

  return followers;
}
```

Sample data from database:

As you can see, `userId 1` can follow `followerId 1` multiple times. (Ignore the fact that they're following themself). Any idea to how I can prevent this from happening? Is there something I can add to the model or would I have to do a  `.findOrCreate(...` function?

```
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | userId | followerId | createdAt           | updatedAt           |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 |          1 | 2016-01-22 05:00:21 | 2016-01-22 05:00:21 |
|  2 |      1 |          1 | 2016-01-22 05:01:28 | 2016-01-22 05:01:28 |
|  3 |      1 |          1 | 2016-01-22 05:39:49 | 2016-01-22 05:39:49 |
|  4 |      1 |          1 | 2016-01-22 07:35:55 | 2016-01-22 07:35:55 |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Find or create is the answer here. Find where userid = id and followerid = followerid. if not found, create it.

Comment: I was thinking, would it be best to ```FIND``` ( IF FOUND THEN DELETE THE COLUMN, **meaning the user is trying to unfollow the particular user** )  & ```IF NOT FOUND```  then simply ```CREATE``` the association? @GrimurD What are your thoughts

Comment: Thats a good idea, makes it a simple toggle then and reduces the code required :)

Comment: If you perform a get before you add to the table, then this should work
if an entity is returned, then do not add.